# Mesh on the other side of light source looks strange

Tags: graphics, 3d, webgl, shader

i'm programming in WebGL (using OpenGL shaders) simple model loader. I've implemented phong shading in fragment shader. However when i load larger objects than simple monkey/cube and turn camera out of light source, meshes looks strange (aliased?). Some of them are even lightened although they should be hidden (black).

Lightened side is OK:
[image: Lightened side is OK]

Other side is wrong:
[image: Other side is wrong]

I calculate normals for every vertex same way, so normals should be OK (when i turn camera on lightened side of car, everything goes right).

Thank you very much for your tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an *single sided* vs *two sided* lighting issue to me. In case your mesh consists of only a single "layer" of faces, those will have normals that point into only one direction. If single sided lighting is used, then the backface, i.e. if the light is on the side from which the normal points away, will look weird.

There are three ways to overcome this:

- Use two sided illumination
- draw the object twice with back faces culled, then flip the normals and culling the front face
- Give the mesh thickness, so that there are two sides (you should enable backface culling then)

Comment: +1: The first thing that struck me too was "this is single-sided lighting".

Comment: Thanks for response, i added backFace normal inversion into my fragment shader this way:


`if (gl_FrontFacing == false) normal = normal * vec3(-1.0,-1.0,-1.0);`


and it helped a bit (interier of this car looks better), but black meshes / polygons are still black and "aliasing dotted lines" are still visible. Is it possible to implement (or just enable) aliasing in OpenGL ES 2.0 easily? It may helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found bug in my Collada Parser where i do not respect exported normals but i'm calculating new one. This causes inverted normals from time to time (this door mesh of this car for example). Anyway two sided rendering has to be implemented too.

Thank you.